# correctly display indentation inside <pre> tag

Tags: slim-lang

What is the recommended method of displaying preformatted text (especially code samples with significant whitespace) with Slim?

For example, how to display the below (with correct indentation) using Slim:

```
<pre>
Vivamus eu lacinia nisi
  Nam pretium urna magna
  Donec sit amet enim ac augue luctus pharetra. 
    Pellentesque dictum
      Enim vel
  Cras risus lectus
</pre>
```

[Embedded engines](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Embedded_engines__Markdown______) are an acceptable answer, but not preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, all you need to do is use the pipe:

```
pre
  | Vivamus eu lacinia nisi
      Nam pretium urna magna
      Donec sit amet enim ac augue luctus pharetra. 
        Pellentesque dictum
          Enim vel
      Cras risus lectus
```

Everything after the pipe is copied over. See the slim docs: http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Text__